# Mouse handling in javascript: I need to lighten the color of the page

Tags: javascript, html

Basically my webpage is a blank and is totally white.

When I move the mouse to the left, it should lighten the background (white). You can think of opacity and all. Or, have a progress bar to handle the lightening and brightening. Initially it should be total bright (navigation bar kind of progress bar should be at right end)

This is my requirement friends, please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you mean slider, not progress bar. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Well this will only halfway work, you still need to account for min/max allowed values of pageY, but should get you started

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    $("body").css("background-color", "rgba(128,128,"+e.pageY+",100)")
});
```

You'll probably even need to create a custom function to derive color based on pageY value, since the above just blindly changes the blue channel, and maybe even convert to hex if you want browser compatibility for those that don't support rgba()